# How to Calculate Pitch Diameter, Angle and distance between two Spheres!

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the Angle [A], Pitch Diameter[P], and Circumferential Clearance depending on how many spheres are in the complement and inner diameter[S]  and outer diameter[B]. According to the following diagram.

[image: Geometry Diagram]

Comment: $A$ is simply the quotient $360º/\text{number of spheres}$, isn't it?

Comment: Your right I see that now, that couldn't be more evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of bearings (circles). Then,
$$A = \frac{360°}{n}$$

Pitch radius is inner radius plus radial clearance plus bearing radius. Using diameters, we need to count the clearance twice:
$$P = S + 2 D + N$$
On the other hand, outer radius is pitch radius plus bearing radius. With diameters, that means
$$B = P + N = S + 2 D + 2 N$$
If we know inner and outer diameter, as well as bearing diameter, then we can solve the radial clearance $D$ from above; it is
$$D = \frac{B - S}{2} - N$$

Circumferential clearance $C$ is a bit tricky, because you have marked it along the dotted circle. If you calculate it that way, you get an overestimate -- as in, you cannot fit a piece of that thickness between the bearings. Consult this diagram instead:
[image: Bearing diagram]
Here, $r = N/2$ and $R = P/2 = (S+N)/2 + D$.
The diagram forms two equal right triangles on top of each other, mirrored vertically, so
$$\sin\frac{A}{2} = \frac{r + C/2}{R}$$
Solving for $C$, and substituting the original variables, we get
$$C = \left(S + N + 2 D\right)\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right) - N = \left(S + N + 2 D\right)\sin\left(\frac{180°}{n}\right) - N$$

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm building a Windows Form Application which is a needle calculator for our engineering department. The circumferential clearance is rarely looked at but is truly a required variable that is kept within a tolerance limit. Now that I have the final formula documented and proven to work. I can now finish my Application and release it after some real world testing to verify it works every time. I really appreciate the time you took to help me with this.

Comment: @StevenWilliams: Nice to hear! I do believe the circumferential clearance is partly overlooked because it is difficult to calculate -- that is, you need that change in perspective from a circular diagram to right triangles to see its properties correctly. I'd bet a pint or two of beer that others have calculated it along the circle -- because that makes sense when you look at the mechanical drawing -- but ignore it when they notice that the clearance is much smaller in practice, chalking it up to machining or something... :) Let me know if you find any discrepancies!

Comment: If you look at the next question found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888265/how-to-calculate-remaining-angle-and-distance-between-two-spheres

Comment: You will see that I agree on the real practices of the actual clearances. @Nominal Animal: Also, I wanted to see if there was a difference in clearance when the bearing had a load and all needles were tangent to one another and to the bore diameter leaving the total circumferential clearance. On my CAD system, it shows the number is different under load and configured as seen in diagram 2 from the second question.