# How to Calculate Remaining Angle and Distance between two Spheres!

Tags: trigonometry

This is my second question which is relevant to the 1st. The 1st is here:
[Click Here to see 1st Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885903/how-to-calculate-pitch-diameter-angle-and-distance-between-two-spheres)

Now that you have seen the 1st question, My second question is:

How to calculate the remaining angle(x), the center points of each needle in the remaining angle(x) and the (Total Circumferential Clearance (C) which can all be seen in Diagram 2:
[image: Diagram 2]

What I have so far is:
n = Total Quantity of N minus 1(In Diagram 2 there are a total of 31 needles in the complement)
$$
y(n) = y(30) = z
$$

So by multiplying the number of (y)angles that should give me the (z)angle. Now I need to figure out how to get the vector points of the two center points of the the two needles in the remaining angle(x). The (C)variable should be obtainable once we have the previously mentioned information. Please let me know if my logic is wrong.

Diagram 2 is a section view of a needle bearing each needle bearing depending on size has a different needle compliment for whatever application it was designed for. Our current needle calculation tool is way outdated and no longer functions. These calculations will help our other engineers design more consistent product by having a tool that makes less mistakes than the long hand calculations they do everyday to figure this out. It's not that I do not trust their calculations but I need to verify their numbers with my own calculations which I'm asking you all to help me with. Also they are unaware of my project as it will be a surprise once I have it finished and working for them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which center have you drawn on the figure? is it the center of the grey circle of diameter $S$ or the white one of diameter $S+D$? You know that the two centers do not coincide and that your picture might be wrong. If you consider the grey circle, then your angles $y$ are all different depending on the position of your grey needles (or whatever you call them)...

Comment: The needles(N) contact the bore diameter(B) and are tangent to (B). The diagram shows the bearing as having a radial load if the Shaft (S) is stationary and the radial load is coming from the top of the assembly. The needle complement is always drawn this way by most bearing manufacturers. I myself have not been able to determine why the industry does this.

Comment: Other than when the actual needles are installed the last needle may have an issue being installed due to the lack of clearance. Then we would use an additional calculation called keystone that allows it to clear the needles. The angles are all centered around the needle complement which as I said are tangent to (B). (D) would be the greatest amount of diametrical clearance under the load. Also on another note, the clearance dimensions shown, (C) & (D) are extreme examples of clearance.

Comment: If I used real numbers you would not be able to see the clearance very well as they are usually measured in Ten-Thousandths of an inch. Thanks for the input, that was a great question.

Comment: From all the numbers B, P, N, D, S, C, y, x on the picture, which ones do you know (given as an input) and which ones are you trying to compute?

Comment: Oh and what exactly is C? The length of the arc of the circle (P) between the two needles or the linear distance between the two needles?

Comment: @Futurologist : We know B, P, N, S, n and D.The C dimension is the smallest distance of space between the 1st and the last needles when all needles are contacting each other and the bore. I guess it would be the linear distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that

- Coordinate system origin is at the center of the bore.
- $B$ is the bore diameter.
- $S$ is the shaft diameter of the shaft.
- $N$ is the needle diameter.
- $P$ is the diameter of the circle formed by the centers of the needles, when pressed against the bore. This means that $$P = B - N$$
- The number of needles $n$

The unknowns are

- The angle $y$ formed by the centers of neighbouring needles, as viewed from the center of the bore

  This also means that $$z = n y$$
- The angle $x$ formed by the centers of the needles spanning the gap, as viewed from the center of the bore, $$x = 360° - z = 360° - n y$$
- Total circumferential clearance $C$
- Maximum radial (diametrical) clearance $D$

From physics we know that a rotating bearing will eventually settle with the gap pressed against the shaft, opposite to the (cumulative) loading force (because that configuration yields the minimum potential energy), assuming perfect measurements and so on.

Therefore, I will consider the following situation:
[image: Bearing under load]

(The potential energy map has only one true minimum, but many local minima (depending on how far the gap is from the above mentioned position). Friction from rolling and/or lubrication, mechanical inaccuracies, and so on mean it is quite possible a *real-world* bearing does not always get into that state. However, it is the *extremum* state, and the one OP is concerned about, if I've understood the problem correctly.)

---

Let's consider $y$ first.

As in the previous question, the angle is composed of two right triangles sharing their hypotenuse. The far side is twice the radius of the needle, or one needle diameter $N$. The near side is the radius of the circle formed by the centers of the needles when pressed against the bore, or half the said diameter; $P/2$. Thus,
$$\tan\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) = \frac{N}{P/2} = \frac{2 N}{P}$$
Solving for $y$ we get
$$y = 2 \arctan\left(\frac{2N}{P}\right) = 2 \arctan\left(\frac{2 N}{B - N}\right)$$

This also gives us $z$,
$$z = n y = 2 n \arctan\left(\frac{2 N}{B - N}\right)$$ 
as well as $x$,
$$x = 360° - n y = 360° - 2 n \arctan\left(\frac{2 N}{B - N}\right)$$

---

Calculating $C$ is exactly the same situation as in my illustration in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1886048/318422) to the OP's [previous related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1885903/318422), with the exception of variable changes $A \to x$ and $R = P/2 = (B-N)/2$ (and $C$ and $r = N/2$ are the same in both), i.e.
$$\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \frac{N/2 + C/2}{B/2 - N/2} = \frac{N + C}{B - N}$$
Substituting $x$ and noting that $\sin(180°-\chi)=\sin(\chi)$ we get
$$\sin\left(n \arctan\left(\frac{2 N }{B - N}\right)\right)  = \frac{N + C}{B - N}$$
and solving for $C$ we get
$$C = \left(B - N\right) \sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{2 N}{B-N}\right)\right) - N $$

---

Calculating $D$ (at its maximum, opposite the gap and furthest from the center of the shaft -- remember the physical assumptions I mentioned earlier) is a bit trickier. Here is one way that should be straightforward to understand.

If we use a coordinate system with the center of the bore at origin, the two needles spanning the gap are at $(u,v)$ and $(-u,v)$, and the center of the shaft is at $(0,d)$; $u \ge 0$, $v \ge 0$, $d \ge 0$. Also, $d \lt v$ (or else the shaft would grind against the bore). Because the shaft is pressed against the needle, the distance between their centers is the sum of their radiuses:
$$\sqrt{\left(u\right)^2 + \left(v - d\right)^2} = \frac{N + S}{2}$$
Solving for $d$ we get
$$d = v \pm \frac{\sqrt{(S + N + 2 u)(S + N - 2 u}}{2}$$
but we need to choose the negative sign so that $0 \le d \lt v$; thus
$$d = v - \frac{\sqrt{(S + N + 2 u)(S + N - 2 u)}}{2}$$
We know that
$$\begin{cases}
u = \frac{B - N}{2} \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right ) \\
v = \frac{B - N}{2} \cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right )
\end{cases} = \begin{cases}
u = \frac{B - N}{2} \sin \left(n \arctan\left(\frac{2 N }{B - N}\right)\right) \\
v = \frac{B - N}{2} \cos \left(n \arctan\left(\frac{2 N }{B - N}\right)\right)
\end{cases}$$
If the shaft displacement is $d$, then the radial clearance $D$ is
$$D = d + \frac{B - N - S}{2}$$
Note that the latter term is the amount of radial clearance if the shaft were centered on the bore. The addition works, because we measure along the line of displacement.

Combining all of the above, we get the rather complicated formula,
$$D = \frac{B - N - S}{2} + \frac{B - N}{2} \cos\left( n \arctan\left(\frac{2 N}{B-N}\right)\right) - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left( S + N + \left(B-N\right)\sin\left(n \arctan\left(\frac{2 N}{B-N}\right)\right)\right)\left( S + N - \left(B-N\right)\sin\left(n \arctan\left(\frac{2 N}{B-N}\right)\right)\right)  }
$$

Comment: 1st. Been busy on another project sorry for not getting back on this subject / issue. Your assumptions are spot on so far. A note to this is that the bore [B], the shaft [S] and the needle [N] all have a tolerance which varies depending on the size of the bearing in question. which means that there will be a minimum and maximum material condition for the calculation. This is better explained as knowing what the tolerances are for each item we can determine maximum clearance and minimum clearance. We can also determine the min and max of the calculated variables as well.

Comment: [Interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) is very useful there. The only gotcha here is to recognize that $\arctan$, $\sin$, and $\cos$ of the minimum and maximum of the range may require splitting the range into three points (two ranges) -- for some interval methods --, if the derivatives at the minimum and maximum have different signs (in which case there is a peak in the middle; the added point being the peak).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am going to assume that the diameter $B$ is known and the diameter of a needle $N$ is also known. That, together with the number of needles, is enough information which allows us to determine everything else.

Assume first that $C$ is the length of the arc between the two needles measured along the circle (P).

For simplicity of notation, denote by $R = \frac{B}{2}$ and $r = \frac{N}{2}$. Let us focus our attention on an isosceles triangle formed by the center of circle $(B)$ and the two centers of two touching needles. Such isosceles triangle has two sides of length $R-r$ and one side of length $2r$, so if we draw the segment connecting the center of $(B)$ with the point of tangency of the two needles, that segment will also be the orthogonal bisector (and also an altitude of the isosceles triangle) of the segment connecting the centers of the two tangent needles. Moreover, it is actually the radius of circle $(P)$ and therefore its length is $\frac{P}{2}$. This way, the isosceles triangle splits into two congruent right-angled triangles and we can easily apply Pythagoras' theorem as well as trigonometric sine or cosine properties in order to arrive at the expressions 
$$P = 2 \sqrt{(R-r)^2 - r^2}$$ and $$y = 2 \arcsin\left( \frac{r}{R-r}\right).$$ Now, in order to determine the arclength $C$, observe that $$x = \frac{y}{2} + \frac{y}{2} + \frac{2C}{P} = y + \frac{C}{\sqrt{(R-r)^2 - r^2}} = 2\arcsin{\left( \frac{r}{R-r}\right)} + \frac{C}{\sqrt{(R-r)^2 - r^2}}.$$
Then all the angles sum up to $2\pi$ giving us the equation
$$2\pi = (n-1)y + x = (n-1)y + y + \frac{C}{\sqrt{(R-r)^2 - r^2}}
= ny + \frac{C}{\sqrt{(R-r)^2 - r^2}}$$  meaning that the arc $(C)$ has length
$$C = (2\pi - ny) \sqrt{(R-r)^2 - r^2} = \left(2\pi - 2\arcsin{\left( \frac{r}{R-r}\right)}\right)\sqrt{(R-r)^2 - r^2}.$$
In particular, $x$ is
$$x = 2\pi - (n-1)y = 2\pi - 2(n-1)\arcsin{\left( \frac{r}{R-r}\right)}.$$ 
Just to be clear, the centers of the needles $(N)$ do not lie on the circle $(P)$. They are located so that the distance between the center of each needle and the center of $(B)$ is $R-r = \frac{1}{2}(B-N).$

If $C$ is actually the (linear) distance between the two needles on top, then
$r + \frac{C}{2} = (R-r)\sin{x}$ which, after solving for $C$, leads to the expression 
$$C = 2(R-r)\sin{x} - 2r = 2(R-r) \sin{\left(2\pi - 2(n-1)\arcsin{\left( \frac{r}{R-r}\right)}\right)} $$ 
$$C= 2(r-R) \sin{\left(2(n-1)\arcsin{\left( \frac{r}{R-r}\right)}\right)}$$

To summarize and write everything in variables $B$ and $N$, 
$$\big(\text{distance b/n center of (B) and the center of a needle}\big)= \frac{1}{2}(B-N),$$
$$P = \sqrt{(B-N)^2 - N^2},$$ 
$$y = 2 \arcsin\left( \frac{N}{B-N}\right),$$
$$x = 2\pi - 2(n-1)\arcsin{\left( \frac{N}{B-N}\right)},$$
$$C = \left(\pi - \arcsin{\left( \frac{N}{B-N}\right)}\right)\sqrt{(B-N)^2 - N^2},$$
in the case when $C$ is the length of a circular arc, or
$$C= (B-N) \sin{\left(2\pi - 2(n-1)\arcsin{\left( \frac{N}{B-N}\right)}\right)}$$ $$ = (N-B) \sin{\left(2(n-1)\arcsin{\left( \frac{N}{B-N}\right)}\right)} $$
in the case when $C$ is the linear distance between the two needles.
Also
$$S = B - 2N -D.$$
depending on what you have and what you need to find.

Comment: Sorry I haven't gotten back with you, been busy on another project. Hopefully I can spend some time on this, this week.